# Can't persist one-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my current project I'm unable to persists a one-to-many relationship.
Both sides of the relationship will be saved - just the link between them is missing.

The one-to-many relationship between my two domains looks like this :

```
class Parent {
    String name
    ...

    static hasMany = [childs: Child]

    Parent() {}

    Parent(SomeOtherClass obj) {
        this.properties = obj.properties  
    }
}

class Child {
    int code
    String description     
}
```

I'm creating my `Parent` instances within a `ParentService`:

```
public Boolean createParents(List parentIds) {
    boolean savedSuccessfully = true
    Parent.withTransaction {status ->
        parentIds.each { parentIdString ->
            if (parentIdString && parentIdString.isInteger()) {
                int parentId = parentIdString.toInteger()

                def parentInstance = new Parent(someOtherService.getExternalParentObj(parentId))

                someOtherService.getExternalChilds(parentId).each { entry ->
                    parentInstance.addToChilds(Child.findOrSaveWhere(code: entry.key, description: entry.value))
                }

                if(!parentInstance.save()) {
                    status.setRollbackOnly()
                    savedSuccessfully = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return savedSuccessfully
}
```

Both, the `Parent` instances and the `Child` instances are created and saved successfully. Just the link between parent and child is missing. The `childs` property of each `Parent` instance is an empty list.

I dont't know what is wrong here.
Why does the relationship won't be persited? Any ideas?

**Update**

I've added an integration test for the `ParentService` to test the existence of the `childs` list after creating all `Parent` instances :

```
...
assert parentService.createParents(["123","234","356"]) == true
def parent = Parent.get(1)
assert parent.childs.size() > 0
...
```

Unexpectedly - the test passed.

Comment: Can you confirm that Grails was able to correctly create the parent, child and parent_child tables

Comment: Yes - all tables are created correctly. The _parent_-table and the _child_-table will be filled. Just the join table _parent_child_ is empty ...

Comment: what are the transactional properties of your ParentService and someOtherService? Have you tried saving/flushing the parent instance prior to calling the other service (and adding the children)?

Comment: @codelark Both services are set to _transactional = false_. I also set it to _true_ but nothing changed. Saving the _parent_ instance before calling _someOtherService_ also doesn't help. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you turned on Hibernate SQL logging to see if the inserts are requested at all? In Datasource.groovy: `datasource { logSql = true }`

Comment: @codelark I checked this once again and could not find a _insert into_ statement for the _parent_child_ table. All other statments are listed - so the logging should be turned on correctly. Any other debugging tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the origin of the error.

I totally missed that some `entry.value` are `null`. Don't know why I didn't see it during debugging.

Now I only use `Child.findOrSaveWhere()` if `entry.value` is not `null`.

I would have expected that the whole `parentInstance.save()` would pass or fail completely. Still don't understand why the join table won't be filled without giving any error.

Comment: Adding the `failOnError: true` argument to `save()` might get you that behavior.